# how to convert C into MIPS assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

```
int sign (int i) { 
 if (i > 0) 
 return 1; 
 else if (i < 0) 
 return -1; 
 else 
 return 0;
```

MIPS

```
.data
  i:       .word
.text
    sign: 
          bgtz i, IF
          bltz i, ELSE
          addi $a0, $zero, $zero
          j END
    IF:   addi $a0, $zero, 1
    ELSE: addi $a0, $zero, -1
    END:  jr $ra
```

OR...

```
.data
  i:       .word
.text
    sign: 
          bgtz i, IF
          bltz i, ELSE
          addi $ra, $zero, $zero
          j END
    IF:   addi $ra, $zero, 1
    ELSE: addi $ra, $zero, -1
    END:  jr $ra
```

i got up to here... how does elseif work in such situation... I tried to search for it but there was not example for me to review and take a look at. Also is this implementation even correct?

Comment: "how to convert C into MIPS assembly code?" - using a MIPS compiler, perhaps?

Comment: `else if` is just another `if` that happens to be in the `else` branch of the first `if`.

Comment: There is no logical reason in the example C code for `else if`, a single `if` will do as well. The second `else` is also useless.

Comment: the second `else` is if `i == 0`. Also, there's nothing wrong with using `else if` in this case. If you use another `if`, you are making the cpu do that comparison every time, even if it doesn't need to.

Comment: I actually taking course in assembly language and this question came up which I didn't have the answer for. I wrote the one above but i am finding the returns awkward to code in MIPS. THe if statement orderings are switched but I did it out of need to practice with the Opcodes

Answer (score 2):

Compile it using the -S option to view the assembly info. i.e `gcc file.c -S file.s`

Comment: That's gonna be x86 AT&T assembly. You need a command line option to convert to MIPS - at least that works from as.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be another way but you can compile it and then disassemble it.

Comment: Just use the compiler in Assembly mode (`-S` for gcc). No need to decompile

Answer (score 0):

This works by branching if `i` is greater than zero or less than zero and continuing
with normal execution if `i = 0`.

```
.data
  i:       .word
.text
    sign: 
          bgtz i, IF // if i greater than zero, go to IF 
          bltz i, ELSE // if i less than zero go to ELSE
          addi $ra, $zero, $zero // If we didn't branch, i not > 0 and i not < 0, i.e. i = 0
          j END
    IF:   addi $ra, $zero, 1 // If body
          j END // Note, I think you need this to avoid also executing the else body
    ELSE: addi $ra, $zero, -1 // else body
    END:  jr $ra
```